# VNC server not working since Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade

Tags: 22.04, xfce, vnc

I have a server with some instances of TigerVNC running to allow for remote access. I am starting them as a systemd service.

Since upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 the servers fail to start with error:

```
Session startup via '/home/VNC/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!
```

Can anyone point me the right direction?

Here is what I have for service def:

```
[Unit]
 Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
 After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
  Type=forking
  User=VNC
  PIDFile=/home/VNC/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
  ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -localhost no -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 :%i
  ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is what I started with for &HOME/.vnc/xstartup:

```
#!/bin/bash
xhost +
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
autocutsel -fork
startxfce4 &
```

I read an article on this forum that talks about new vncserver needs to run in foreground so take the "&" off the startxfce4 command. I did this and the service starts. I can access from remote computer, ***however***, after about 1min the service stops with an error:
Job for vncserver@1.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.

Here is the systemctl status:

```
VNC@HP-EliteDesk-800:~/.vnc$ systemctl status vncserver@1.service
× vncserver@1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@1.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2022-08-22 10:31:01 MDT; 2min 40s ago
    Process: 14603 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 14606 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -localhost no -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 :1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 4.972s

Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Activating service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar8' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1001 pid=14753 comm=>
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1001 pid=14730 comm="xfdesktop " label=">
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar8'
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.41' (uid=1001 pid=14941 comm="/usr/libexec/evolution-ca>
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Activating service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook10' requested by ':1.41' (uid=1001 pid=14941 c>
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook10'
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' requested by ':1.26' (uid=1001 pid=14786 comm="/>
Aug 22 10:29:30 HP-EliteDesk-800 dbus-daemon[14633]: [session uid=1001 pid=14631] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue in the meantime? I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 yesterday, and am experiencing the same issue since.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Happens when vncserver is started from the terminal too.

Comment: In my case it was because The global config file for tigervncserver has moved from `/etc/vnc.conf` to `/etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-defaults` but that doesn't appear to be the OP's issue.